# Find string inside pdf with shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, pdf

I'd like to know if there is any way to check if there is a string inside a `pdf` file using a shell script? I was looking for something like:

```
if [search(string,pdf_file)] > 0 then  
   echo "exist"
fi
```

Comment: This seems to be very closely related to [Grep PDF Files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/grep-pdf-files), for which the answers may solve your problem too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nicely pointed by Simon, you can simply convert the `pdf` to plain text using `pdftotext`, and then, just search for what you're looking for.

After conversion, you may use `grep`, bash regex, or any variation you want:

```
while read line; do

    if [[ ${line} =~ [0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} ]]; then
        echo ">>> Found date;";
    fi

done < <(pdftotext infile.pdf -)
```

Answer (score 3):

This approach converts the .pdf files page-wise, so the occurences of the search string `$query` can be located more specifically.

```
# search for query string in available pdf files pagewise
for i in *.pdf; do
    pagenr=$(pdfinfo "$i" | grep "Pages" | grep -o "[0-9][0-9]*")
    fileid="\n$i\n"
    for (( p=1; p<=pagenr; p++ )); do
        matches=$(pdftotext -q -f $p -l $p "$i" - | grep --color=always -in "$query")
        if [ -n "$matches" ]; then
            echo -e "${fileid}PAGE: $p"
            echo "$matches"
            fileid=""
        fi
    done
done
```

`pdftotext -f $p -l $p` limits the range to be converted to only one page identified by the number `$p`. `grep --color=always` allows for protecting match highlights in the subsequent `echo`. `fileid=""` just makes sure the file name of the .pdf document is only printed once for multiple matches.

Answer (score 1):

Very old question but still relevant. You can use https://pdfgrep.org/

ex. to search in all pdf the words "My string":

`pdfgrep --page-number --ignore-case "My string" *.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Each letter within a PDF doc is typically set individually. Therefore, you have to convert the .pdf to text, which will reduce the text to a simple stream.

I would try this:

```
grep -q 'a \+string' <(pdf2text some.pdf - | tr '\n' ' ') && echo exists
```

The `tr` joins line breaks. The `\+` allows for 1 or more space chars between words. Finally, `grep -q` only returns exit status `0/1` based on a match. It does not print matching lines.