# How to find a multiple line string in a file using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to find the string `"Time series prediction with ensemble models"` in a pdf file using shell script. I am using `pdftotext`

```
$file - | grep $string
```

where `$file` is the pdf file name and `$string` is the above string. It can find out the line if the entire string contains in a line but it can't find out line like this

```
Time series prediction with
ensemble models
```

How can I resolve it? I am new to linux so explanation in detail is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please visit this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449968/find-string-inside-pdf-with-shell

Comment: for multiline grep you can refer to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep

Answer (score 1):

pdftotext may put some spaces between words because of the nature of the pdf format. So to catch all posibilities. It runs as you want.

```
pdftotext "$file" | grep -ozi "Time\s\+series\s\+prediction\s\+with\s\+ensemble\s\+models"
```

from man of grep

```
-o, --only-matching
          Print only the matched (non-empty) parts  of  a  matching  line,
          with each such part on a separate output line.

-z, --null-data
          Treat  the  input  as  a set of lines, each terminated by a zero
          byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.   Like  the
          -Z  or --null option, this option can be used with commands like
          sort -z to process arbitrary file names.

-i, --ignore-case
          Ignore  case  distinctions  in  both  the  PATTERN and the input
          files.  (-i is specified by POSIX.)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-z` option available with `gnu-grep` for this:

```
pdftotext "$file" | grep -z "Time series prediction with.*ensemble models"
```

As per `man grep`:

```
-z, --null-data
     Treat  the  input  as  a  set  of  lines,  each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII
     NUL character) instead of a newline. Like the -Z or --null option, this option can be
     used with commands like sort -z to process  arbitrary file names.
```